# android/java: passing nested classes between activities

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I'm not sure of the best way to pass the outer class between activities.  Should I make them both parcelable?  Just not sure how to do the parcelable array in the writeToParcel method.

```
public class checklistItem  {

    String name;
    String date;
        ...
}

public class dailyChecklist  {

    ...
    checklistItem[] theList;
    ...
}
```

Comment: The easiest way: make the nested class non-nested, save it somewhere as a global variable, access it from both activities.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the Application class in your app and create a reference there to the instanced object you want to share across activities.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A non-static nested class contains an hidden reference to its enclosing outerclass; which can be useful sometimes but useless on other occasions. If you don't need to call your outerclass from the inner class then you should declare your inner class as static.  This way, it will behave as an ordinary, non-nested class but its definition will still remains in the namespace of the outer class.

Of course, for the purists, by `class`, I means here an instance (object) of that class.